# Calling asp.net core API from my Angular@5.2.0 app and getting this "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error

Tags: api, asp.net-core, angular5, httprequest

**I am just trying to call my .net core API function from my Angular v5.2.0 app and i getting "GET http://localhost:5000/api/values net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   zone.js:3243"**

***This is my component.js file which i'm using to call the api.***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-value',
  templateUrl: './value.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./value.component.css']
})
export class ValueComponent implements OnInit {

  values: any;
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetValues();
  }

  GetValues() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/values').subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

This is the error i'm getting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM09D.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your UI(angular) code and api run on same port

I can see in image the UI runs on localhost:4200 and you are trying to call api on localhost:5000

make sure localhost:5000 is up and running and try to get data with any client such as postman.